# Code Highlight and cursor position in a StructuredTextEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

My own plugin project has a editor(which implements org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart) with 2 pages:one is a **GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette**(which will parse XML files into figures) and the other one is a **StructuredTextEditor**(which will parse figures into XML code).So what I want to do is drawing figures in the first editor and get source code in the other editor and do the opposite thing as well.And I believe many GEF and plugin/RCP projects may have this feature.

Now I have to face the fact that when I try to switch between my two editors,the cursor always stay on the first line in the source Editor.What I supposed to get is that if a figure is **selected** in the first editor and when I switch to the second editor,some code block should be highlight(just like the Outline View in Eclipse),or at least the cursor should stay at the line which the corresponding XML block starts(just like the XML Editor in Eclipse)

Anybody have some helpful advice to give?
Tks a lot :-)

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but you should be at least aware that there are frameworks that make building this kind of editors much easier. I recommend that you can take a look at Sapphire (http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/) so that you can concentrate on implementing the semantics of the file you are editing instead of the details of how editor pages are synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

In the GEF editor, you can listen to selection changes using a `SelectionEditPolicy`'s `showSelection` method.  This method will get called when your selection changes. In the method you can change the location where the cursor is shown on your second editor (or set some kind of shared variable that can be read by the editor when it gets activated).